# Pandas: check if any of the values in a subset of a column respect condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing a datetime column, a condition, a counter of how many consecutive times such condition happens, and a value column. It looks like:

```
date                      condition        count        Value 
01,01,2018 08:00             A               1            9
01,01,2018 08:01             A               2            9
01,01,2018 08:02             A               3            9
01,01,2018 08:03             B               1            9
01,01,2018 08:04             B               2            9
01,01,2018 08:05             B               3            4
01,01,2018 08:06             B               4            9
01,01,2018 08:07             C               1            9
01,01,2018 08:08             C               2            9
01,01,2018 08:09             C               3            9
01,01,2018 08:10             C               4            9
```

I need an error column, that return 1 in all the rows between 1 and 3 and condition = B when:

-condition = B

-count <= 3

-at least one value < 5

The desired outcome is:

```
enter code here
         date                condition         count        Value    error
    01,01,2018 08:00             A               1            9         0
    01,01,2018 08:01             A               2            9         0
    01,01,2018 08:02             A               3            9         0
    01,01,2018 08:03             B               1            9         1
    01,01,2018 08:04             B               2            9         1
    01,01,2018 08:05             B               3            4         1
    01,01,2018 08:06             B               4            9         0
    01,01,2018 08:07             C               1            9         0
    01,01,2018 08:08             C               2            9         0
    01,01,2018 08:09             C               3            9         0
    01,01,2018 08:10             C               4            9         0
```

I have tried:

```
df['error']=np.where((df['condition']=='B') & (df['count']<=5) & ((df['Value']).all()>=5), 1, 0)


df['error']=np.where((df['condition']=='B') & (df['count']<=5) & (df.value.apply(lambda x: x<5).any()),0,1)
```

but none of them seems to work. Can you help me? Thank you :)

Comment: Does that one value less than 5 have to be larger than zero? Also, if your B with count 2 had a value of 12 but everything else stayed the same, then would your error columns still be as it is in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.loc[(df['condition']=='B')&(df['count']<=3),'error']=1
```

**Demo (do as full code):**

```
df = your data
df['error']=0
df.loc[(df['condition']=='B')&(df['count']<=3),'error']=1
print(df)
```

Output:

```
             date condition  count  Value  error
01,01,2018  08:00         A      1      9      0
01,01,2018  08:01         A      2      9      0
01,01,2018  08:02         A      3      9      0
01,01,2018  08:03         B      1      9      1
01,01,2018  08:04         B      2      9      1
01,01,2018  08:05         B      3      4      1
01,01,2018  08:06         B      4      9      0
01,01,2018  08:07         C      1      9      0
01,01,2018  08:08         C      2      9      0
01,01,2018  08:09         C      3      9      0
01,01,2018  08:10         C      4      9      0
```

Now it's as expected.

Comment: This doesn't check for the condition "at least one value < 5"

Comment: Thank you, but where the condition "if any value is < 5" is? your code seems simply to assign 1 for count<=3 and condition=B

Comment: @Luca91 Ypu meant at least one value in the roe?

Comment: @U9-Forward at least one value, under condition=B and count<=3, is < 5. then assign error=1 to all rows under condition = B and count<=3

Comment: @Luca91 To `Value` column?

Comment: @Luca91 does `0` count as a value less than `5`? Also what if the values were `[0,12,4]`, then does you want errors on all three still?

Comment: no, 0 doesn't count, now I edit the values so that it doesn't cause this issue ;) but thanks for noticing

Comment: It works, but when I test changing the values, all=9, in order to have 0 error in all the rows, it doesn't update and remains error=1 in those rows. I have no idea why

Comment: Now I undersood why, basically before I have another situation where the conditions are fulfilled, so it correctly assigns the error. However, it is assigned also after where just the condition =B and count<=3 are fulfilled, even if value is not <5

Comment: @Luca91 Then can use it without the `<5` thing, that works, then can accept? :-),

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i'm understanding your use correctly, but this might work for you

```
mask = ((df['condition'] == 'B') & (df['count'] <= 5))

if df.loc[mask, 'Value'].min() < 5:
    df.loc[mask, 'Error'] = 1
```

The tricky thing is that you're setting values in one row based on the group of rows. I'm not super happy with this as an answer because for a lot of use cases it won't scale.

I think the general case would be to group by the columns you are considering conditions of, take the minimum of 'Value' and join that back to the dataframe, which gives you a minimum value column you can use for a row-wise comparison... I'm not sure I could write you an example of that without seeing what you're actually doing in a more general example.